# ¿Como realizar un LIKE en Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Voy a reformular mejor la pregunta:
¿como puedo hacer un like en linq?

Comment: pero que es Filter() ? o sea que linq define

Comment: para convertir de un WS_Product a ProductDto porque no usas automapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Hola leandro.. justo me estaba acordando que use el codigo que publicaste en tu blog acerca de ef (lo he usado muchas veces y ya ni me acordaba que lo publicaste tu haha). No puedo usar automapper, el requerimiento me lo impide.. por eso hago el mapeo de esta forma. ya me funciono con el contain que me indica mas abajo Jhon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya probaste la extensión .Contains de LINQ? Cuando utilizas '==' debe ser igual la "descripción" (en tu caso) con el valor de la variables Descriptino, sin embargo con .Contains busca dentro de la Descripción algo igual al valor de la variable Description, por lo que no será necesario buscar la descripción completa para lograrla filtrar, quedaría algo como:

```
private List<ProductDto> _GetProductByDescription(string Description)
{
    WS_ProductRepository productRepo = new WS_ProductRepository();
    List<WS_Product> lstProducts = productRepo.Filter(x => x.Description.Contains(Description));
    if (lstProducts != null && lstProducts.Count > 0)
    {
        List<ProductDto> lstProductDto = new List<ProductDto>();
        foreach (WS_Product product in lstProducts)
        {
            ProductDto productDto = new ProductDto();
            productDto.ProductId = product.ProductId;
            productDto.Description = product.Description;
            productDto.CategoryId = product.CategoryId;
            productDto.Price = product.Price;
            lstProductDto.Add(productDto);
        }
        return lstProductDto;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Super. me funciono muy bien. gracias..